# How to resample datetime data to get only the specifc hours of the day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filtering

So I have some stock data that is for every minute over the 2020. Though my issue is that I only want the data from 9:30 in the morning to 4:00 in the afternoon. Currently the data includes afterhour prices as well which I would like to filter out. The code for the data is:

```
import pandas as pd

#get stock prices
d = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\B1880\Downloads\AMD_stock_data\AMD_2020_2020.txt")
d.columns = ['Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
d.index.name = 'Dates'
```

The URL for the data is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxVjEJkEmDZwu44pNxsg5ZBonqbTFak8HoESbxo0AM0/edit#gid=1360727590
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: By this I assuming you mean that the data I am providing is not up to standards for you to test. Though my issue is how do I recreate a sample data frame for datetime data? Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `"Dates"` columns to datetime and then filter by time.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> amd_df["Dates"] = amd_df["Dates"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
>>> amd_df = amd_df[amd_df["Dates"].dt.time >= datetime.time(hour=9, minute=30)]
>>> amd_df = amd_df[amd_df["Dates"].dt.time <= datetime.time(hour=16, minute=0)]
```

Comment: Thank You, this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df2 = df.set_index('Dates')
df2 = df2.between_time('9:30', '16:00')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, though now I am getting the error: TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex